# Value of input is from a file

Tags: html

```
<input id="LoadText" value= 'data.txt' />
```

I am trying to give the default value of the LoadText input to the contents of the 'data.txt' file.

Comment: Are you saying you want to read the `data.txt` file and load it into a form? You are going to need either some server side code or javascript to accomplish that, if that is what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a dynamic programming langauge to achieve this behaviour. You could use a serverside technology like PHP to read the content of data.txt and insert its content into the html before sending the file to the client. Or you can use clientside technology like Javascript to load the data.txt file speratly and insert it into the input form afterwards.

Update PHP example:

If your webspace/server/etc supports PHP you could simply write something like this:

```
<input id="LoadText" value= '<?php echo file_get_contents('data.txt'); ?>' />
```

But you need to take care of the content of data.txt . The file could contain anything and therefore break your design. Just imagine the following content:

```
' /><any tag and code you do not want in your design
```

Comment: Can you put the PHP code right into the value attribute or somewhere else?

Comment: If your webspace/server/etc supports PHP you could simply write something like this:
    <input id="LoadText" value= '<?php echo file_get_contents('data.txt'); ?>' />

But you need to take care of the content of data.txt . The file could contain anything and therefore break your design. Just imagine the following content: "' /><any tag and code you do not want in your design>"

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** This is a solution, if the file data.txt is stored on the local file system of the client, if it is stored on the server, please have a look at Daniel's solution...

To read a local file into your site there a mainly two possible solutions:

- Uploading the file to the server and download it again with [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax)
- Use the [File API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_File_API). The current support for it can be seen on this site: http://caniuse.com/fileapi

If you store your HTML file also on your local file system (and you never want it to be stored on a server), you can also directly use AJAX. Here is a code using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "data.txt",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function (data) {
        // do something with the text of data.txt (which is stored in the value data)
    }
});
```

The files `data.txt` and your HTML file must be stored in the same directory for this.

Comment: Good point, I didn't think about the fact, that data.txt could already be on the client.